# There is a bijection from the set of double cosets $F g F$ to the set of orbits of $X$ under $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions

I'm doing **Exercise 9(b)** in textbook *Algebra* by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff. Could you please verify if it is fine or contains logical mistakes?

[image]

> If $G$ acts transitively on a set $X$, then the subgroup $F$ fixing a point $x_{0} \in X$ also acts on $X$. Show that there is a bijection from the set of all double cosets $F g F$ to the set of orbits of $X$ under $F$.

---

**My attempt:**

Consider a map $FgF \mapsto F(gx_0)$.

First, we prove it's well-defined. Let $g,h \in G$. Then $FgF = FhF \iff gh^{-1}\in F$. Because $F$ is the subgroup fixing $x_0$, we have $gx_0 = h x_0 \iff gh^{-1} \in F$. Hence $FgF = FhF \iff gx_0 = h x_0 \implies F(gx_0) = F(hx_0)$.

Because $G$ acts transitively on $X$, every $x \in X$ can be written as $g x_0$ for some $g \in G$. Hence the map is surjective.

Second, we prove it's injective. Assume  $F(gx_0) = F(hx_0)$, which is equivalent to $gx_0$ and $hx_0$ are in the same orbit. This is in turn equivalent to $\exists g' \in F:g' (gx_0) = hx_0$. This implies $(g'g)h^{-1} \in F$. Because $g' \in F$, we have $gh^{-1} \in F$. This implies $FgF = FhF$.

---

**Update:** @Anirban Bose pointed out in a comment that the well-definedness part is incorrect. Here is my fix:

Let $g,h \in G$. Then $FgF=FhF\iff g=f_1hf_2$ for some $f_1,f_2 \in F$. It follows from $f_2 \in F$ that $gx_0 = f_1hf_2x_0 = f_1 (h x_0)$. It follows from $f_1 \in F$ that $gx_0$ and $hx_0$ are equivalent under $F$. As a result, $F(gx_0) = F(hx_0)$.

Comment: Correction : $FgF=FhF\Leftrightarrow g=f_1hf_2$ for some $f_1,f_2\in F$. Accordingly the arguments for well-defined-ness and injectivity must be corrected.

Comment: Hi @AnirbanBose. I have updated my post with the correction for the well-defined-ness. It's wrong that $FgF = FhF \iff gh^{-1}\in F$, but it's true that $gh^{-1}\in F \implies FgF = FhF$. Please see my update.

Comment: Yeah now it's correct. And yes your proof of injectivity stands correct. I did not notice it then. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification @AnirbanBose! I hope you post your first comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: You are welcome @LAD. Well you yourself almost provided with the answer. So really there is nothing more that I would want to add. Only a small repairing need to be done tht's all.

Comment: @AnirbanBose you corrected my logical misunderstanding, which is critical for my study. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad that I could be of some help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is  @Anirban Bose's comment that answers my question. I post it here to remove this question from unanswered list. All credits are given to @Anirban Bose.

> Correction : $FgF=FhF\Leftrightarrow g=f_1hf_2$ for some $f_1,f_2\in F$. Accordingly the arguments for well-defined-ness and injectivity must be corrected.